# Could not transfer artifact org.primefaces\:primefaces\:pom\:3.1

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, proxy

I am trying to configure maven I am getting the following error

```
https\://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.primefaces\:primefaces\:pom\:3.1 from/to maven2-repository.dev.java.net (https\://maven.java.net/content/groups/public)\: connection timed out
```

I have added proxy settings in D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\apache-maven-3.0.4\conf\settings.xml

```
<proxies>
   <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |-->
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>myid</username>
      <password>mypassword</password>
      <host>proxyaddress</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>
```

Even after adding proxy in settings why I am getting connection timed out error?

Any help is highly appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, was quite silly. I removed `-->` after `</proxy>.`